# Why ShaderNodeMix output is_linked returns False?

Tags: python, shader-nodes

When I run this code in 3.6 it returns `False`.

```
D.materials['Material'].node_tree.nodes['Mix'].outputs[0].is_linked -> False
```

[image]

Comment: can be different reasons....could you pls provide blend file? thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because the mix node actually has several outputs, which are selectively dynamically hidden when you change the node mode. If you use it as Float mode, it will use a float socket output, if you use it as Vector mode, it will have a vector output. All these output sockets are different under the hood. I would try with `outputs[1]` or `outputs[2]`.

```
import bpy

node = bpy.data.materials['Material'].node_tree.nodes['Mix']
print(node.outputs[0].is_linked) # Float mode
print(node.outputs[1].is_linked) # Vector mode
print(node.outputs[2].is_linked) # Color mode
```

Comment: it's 2 :D just learned again from you

Comment: @Chris yup. It's a shame there is no way to learn this using only the interface, one has to try out several options to get the right one. Plus they are all called "Result" so you can't search sockets by name. :)

Comment: yeah. Blender help is partially good - but you won't find such detailed information. It's really a shame.

Comment: An idiomatic (I think) way to access the right output here would be: `next(o for o in node.outputs if o.name=='Result' and o.type=='RGBA')`, or perhaps more readable especially if next to similar code, `next(o for o in node.outputs if (o.name, o.type) == ('Result', 'RGBA'))`

Answer (score 1):

Its because several outputs are called the same thing.

You might be using a *Vector* result, but `outputs['Result']` will return the color one.

The input/outputs could really do with renaming (*ColResult*, *VecResult* etc)

Comment: It's not that easy - the change would break existing code. A new attribute holding the unique name could be added - but someone who doesn't know to check for a type of the socket, probably also wouldn't know to read `uniquename` instead of `name`.

Comment: Like they care at all about breaking existing code. They totally trashed the node group interface with the most retarded design decisions. you could still map the new ones to the old names if you want existing code to work.